# Unable to scan a docker image with trivy?

Tags: trivy

Hi I have installed trivy on my machine . I am trying to scan python docker image using trivy . unfortunately i am behind the corporate network proxy. how can i bypass the proxy.

I get the following error

```
$trivy image python:3.4-alpine


DB error: failed to download vulnerability DB: failed to download vulnerability DB: failed to list releases: Get "https://api.github.com/repos/aquasecurity/trivy-db/releases": dial tcp 140.82.121.5:443: i/o timeout
```

i have details of my corporate proxy . how can make the image scan work.

appreciate if you can help

Comment: Have you set the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY (and http_proxy, https_proxy) environment variables?

Comment: yeah that works thank you